# PHP array with mysql joined result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query to a database with a join.

My tables in the database do have some names that are not unique. Ie in the "event" table there is a `dsc` coloumn and in `module` table there is a `dsc` coloumn.

My question is, when i bring the results of a JOIN table query into a php array, how do i select between the two different table fields.

So for one i would say $result['dsc'];

I thought something like $resuilt['event.dsc'];

Doesnt seem too work though :/

Answer (score 1):

You can select them as different names in your query:

```
SELECT `module`.`dsc` AS `mdsc`, `event`.`dsc` AS `edsc` ...
```

Then,

```
$result["mdsc"]; $result["edsc"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the alias for column name

```
select module.dsc as mod_dsc, event.dsc as edsc ....
```